# Transposing pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like,

```
index  price   Date
A      2       XX
B      3       XX
C      4       XX
```

The date is same in all rows.

I want it transformed as,

```
Index    A    B    C
 XX      2    3    4
```

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Date',columns='index',values='price')`

Comment: Thanks @Wen worked perfectly